# upload image and sending parameter in android using base64

Tags: java, php, android

I am uploading in android. To do so I am following this [tutorial](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/). My current code gives me this error in my logcat

```
06-23 10:10:22.990: D/dalvikvm(25853): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 48K, 50% free 2723K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 33ms
06-23 10:10:23.030: E/log_tag(25853): Error in http connection java.net.UnknownHostException: www.example.info
06-23 10:10:23.115: D/CLIPBOARD(25853): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
```

Here is how my code looks like

```
public class UploadFileActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button bUpload;
EditText etParam;

InputStream is;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

    byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba, 0);

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.info/androidfileupload/index.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

}
}
```

Here is what I am using on the server side

```
<?php
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];

echo $base;

// base64 encoded utf-8 string

$binary=base64_decode($base);

// binary, utf-8 bytes

header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

// print($binary);

//$theFile = base64_decode($image_data);

$file = fopen('test.jpg', 'wb');

fwrite($file, $binary);

fclose($file);

echo '<img src=test.jpg>';

?>
```

Comment: Sometimes it happens also if Permission already taken, Just Restart `Wifi` or `MobileData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UnknownHostException` is related to your url domain or there is no Internet/Network connectivity,

So make sure you have added Internet permission in your AndroidManifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Hope This Helps

Comment: Thanks it works. Could you tell me how can I keep the name of the image as original name? I mean, I want to use that same name of the image at the time of uploading.

Answer (score 2):

I followed that same tutorial. Worked as long as the images were small enough.

Otherwise you can get an Out Of Memory issue at:

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

To answer you question -

> Could you tell me how can I keep the name of the image as original
>   name? I mean, I want to use that same name of the image at the time of
>   uploading.

You can add a variable to the URL request that holds the original name. Otherwise you won't be able to embed it into the 64Byte encoded string.

Something like this:

```
"http://www.example.info/androidfileupload/index.php?name=filename"
```

PHP side looks like

```
$FileName = $_GET['name'];
```